# Dateformatter is returning arabic string instead english iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dateformatter

App language and device language is set to arabic, then in date formatter changing the locale to "en_US_POSIX" but its still giving arabic string.

```
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") 
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
        let dateTime = dateFormatter.date(from:"2021-03-16 08:00")!
        print("\(dateTime)")
```

> // Output ٢٠٢١-٠٣-١٦ ٠٢:٣٠:٠٠ +0000

Comment: Is it possible that you're reusing the formatter and setting the locale at some other place in your code?

Comment: i checked it . i am not reusing the dateformatter

Comment: @Codecracker Is it possible that the `print()` function is localizing the output? What do you get when using the `dateFormatter` to produce a string representation of your `dateTime`? (`print(dateFormatter.string(from: dateTime))`)

Comment: i mentioned it as output in question

Comment: The output in your question comes from printing the `Date`, not the string resulting from formatting the date.

Comment: you can see the print statement in the code snippet i added. I got that arabic string in console. i mentioned it as output for better understanding

Comment: Once you get a `Date` it doesn't matter what formatter was used to create it - it's now a pure date representation - it doesn't have a format or a style. When you `print` it, the `print` function uses the system formatter to convert it back into a text representation that you see on the screen. If you want to control how it prints, use the date formatter to output it back to text

Comment: i tried to display that in label, its coming in arabic in label @NewDev

Comment: @Codecracker, re-read the comments carefully - you have 3 people telling you the same thing in different ways. Of course it would output as arabic if that's the system locale - you need to apply a formatter to the output if you want to control it

Comment: And here is a 4th person, print the date using `description(with:)`. First using your locale, `print(dateTime.description(with: .current))` and also with the locale used by the formatter, `print(dateTime.description(with: Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")))` and notice the difference

Comment: Thank you all ...